# JSF <h:commandButton action> not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

`<h:commandButton action>` is not working in following code snippest.

bean(Employee.java):-

```
        public String deleteEmployee(){
        return "success3";
            }
```

JSF page(delete-employee.xhtml):-

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="employee.deleteEmployee" type="submit" value="delete"/>
</h:form>
```

Faces-config.xml:-

```
    <managed-bean>
      <description>Employee navigation</description>
      <managed-bean-name>employee</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>erpJavaFiles.Employee</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/add-Employee.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/CRM.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/delete-employee.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success3</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/CRM.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Second navigation rule is not working but the first navigation rule is working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you still using the `faces-config.xml` approach? JSF 2.0 offers annotations for managed beans and implicit navigation. http://blogs.sun.com/rlubke/entry/faces_config_xml_we_don Anyway, the missing EL `#{}` in the `action` attribute is also a "typo", right?

Comment: V v v thanks BalusC.But ur provided link does not work, kindly send it again.

Comment: The page is down. In the meantime, see http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/index.html#Basics - all-around solid JSF tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `employee` in the `<from-view-id>`.

```
<from-view-id>/delete-employee.xhtml</from-view-id>
```

Comment: -Thanks very much kindly chek again.

Comment: The filename in the question still does not match the `<from-view-id>`. You might also need to fix the capitalization: `<from-view-id>/delete-Employee.xhtml</from-view-id>` but I don't actually know what the name of the file is.